# Overloading Operator= for a class that inherit a std list in C++

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading

```
class A : protected list<Type*>
```

I know that it's a bad practice to inherit from std, but, only for testing: an operator= for this class should have to equalize the elements of the given class list. So, how can i do this directly (without iterating the two list)? And so (assuming that c is the given object, overloading the operator=) `(*this) = c` or something like `(*this) = c.list` ?

So, is this correct?

```
void A::operator=(const A& c)
{
    (*this) = c;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think you can do a proper implementation of `operator==` without iterating the list?

Comment: Sorry, i confused the operator, my question was for the operator=.

Comment: What if the lists in each object are not the same size?  You really shouldn't be using `operator=` for business logic like this.  Create a `set_equal` function or similar.

Comment: My question still stands despite the change of operator. The operator will need to work with every element of the list, right?

Comment: 1) There's nothing wrong with inheriting from a `std` container. 2) Are you trying to ask how to invoke `std::list`'s assignment operator, as part of the assignment operator of your subclass?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, some people [strongly suggest](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/) that standard types should not be inherited.

Comment: If one accepts everything that everyone "strongly suggests" on the Internet, they won't be able to write a single C++ program, because, on matter what, someone will "strongly suggest" that it's a bad idea.

Comment: Unclear (to me): what does _"... to equalize the elements..."_ mean?  What are you trying to do with the 2 lists and why/how is this different from assignment (the expected operation)?

Comment: Exactly the assignment.

Comment: I edited the post.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::fill(lst.begin(), lst.end(), value)`?